# adding a new wpdb class in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a new class wpdb                                                         **$wpdb1 = new wpdb(my_db_login, my_db_password, my_DB_NAME,my_DB_HOST);** for my wordpress blog but I don't know where.
when I put it the following class in wp-config i got this error message
Fatal error: Class 'wpdb' not found in line 80 , sorry i'm a wordpress beginer

Answer (score 0):

What are you attempting to do? The wpdb class is loaded after wp-config.php so you can't use it there (not that you should anyway).

If you want to run a custom DB query in your code then use global $wpdb; You don't need to instantiate it and attempt to open a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

Include wp-load.php file before using class.

```
<?php
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php'); // This is a case called at themes/foobar. Put your relative path to root of WP.
$wpdb = new wpdb();
?>
```

Comment: If the poster uses the class correctly this won't be necessary. They state they're trying to add it to wp-config.php

Comment: The error is "Fatal error: Class 'wpdb' not found in line 80", that means class is unloaded.
I guessed the poster use the class as a isolated script file.